# Postgres query for duplicates hangs only in some environments

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a relatively large PostgreSQL (v12) table storing JSONB data that has unintentional duplicate data (based on a composite unique index on two columns, `aCol` and `bCol`). In order to create that index, I have to first delete all of the accidental duplicates from the DB. This works fine in 2/3 of our DB servers (servers for different environments, i.e. Dev and Prod, all with the same DB schema), but in the 3rd the query will just never finish, and I've let it run for up to 2 hours (in the other environments it takes a matter of minutes).

I've tried configuring the resources and configuration settings to be the same in all environments; for example, the RAM, disk size and ops, CPU, `effective_io_concurrency`, etc. I've also compared the sizes of the tables and I don't think that's the issue, because one of the servers that does complete has ~2 million records for a total of ~9 GB while the one that fails has ~400,000 records for a total of ~2 GB.

The query in question is:

```sql
DELETE FROM aTable a USING aTable b
WHERE a.aCol = b.aCol
    AND a.bCol = b.bCol
    AND a.id != b.id
    AND a.created_at <= b.created_at
```

I'm not a DBA or SQL expert by any means so I would definitely appreciate any insight into what else might be causing this query to hang in 1 specific environment, or whether there is a more efficient way to achieve what I'm trying to do that could potentially bypass the issue. Thanks in advance

**Edit:** In response to the comments, here are the explain plans for the queries in the two environments.

Working environment:

```
Delete on aTable a  (cost=800504.63..5706702.06 rows=72439076 width=12)
  ->  Merge Join  (cost=800504.63..5706702.06 rows=72439076 width=12)
        Merge Cond: ((a.aCol = b.aCol) AND (a.bCol = b.bCol))
        Join Filter: ((a.id <> b.id) AND (a.created_at <= b.created_at))
        ->  Sort  (cost=400252.31..404391.52 rows=1655683 width=50)
              Sort Key: a.aCol, a.bCol
              ->  Seq Scan on aTable a  (cost=0.00..184763.83 rows=1655683 width=50)
        ->  Materialize  (cost=400252.31..408530.73 rows=1655683 width=50)
              ->  Sort  (cost=400252.31..404391.52 rows=1655683 width=50)
                    Sort Key: b.aCol, b.bCol
                    ->  Seq Scan on aTable b  (cost=0.00..184763.83 rows=1655683 width=50)
```

Failing environment:

```
Delete on aTable a  (cost=0.00..1794266.00 rows=59613596 width=12)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..1794266.00 rows=59613596 width=12)
        ->  Seq Scan on aTable a  (cost=0.00..40365.00 rows=395600 width=50)
        ->  Index Scan using idx_aTable_aCol on aTable b  (cost=0.00..4.42 rows=1 width=50)
              Index Cond: (aCol = a.aCol)
              Filter: ((a.id <> id) AND (a.created_at <= created_at) AND (a.bCol = bCol))
```

I notice that the failing table seems to be trying to use a hash index on `aCol`, though the tables in both environments have that exact same index. Not really sure what to make of that, because if anything, I figured that would've sped things up

**Edit #2:** It's also worth noting that I tried setting up a fresh database server with the same schema, where I imported csv dumps of all of the tables from the failing environment. The query failed to run in that test instance as well, so that at least indicates that the issue is not actually with the environment itself

Comment: Did you check for row locks? If another proces tries to update or delete a single record from the set you try to delete, everything has to wait until the end of the first transaction.

Comment: @FrankHeikens I didn't do that yet, let me try that. I did do a `SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE datname = 'aTable'` to see if any connections were open and none were

Comment: @FrankHeikens ok so I do see some `AccessShareLocks` for that table in `pg_locks`, but they only appear when the query is running so I feel like it's coming from the query itself

Comment: Can you give the EXPLAIN outputs for the query, both on an environment which finishes and one that doesn't?

Comment: @jjanes sure, just added them to the original post

Comment: @jjanes wow ok so based on that explain plan I tested dropping the index from the DB in the failing environment and now the query completes almost instantly... Any idea why that would be the case? It's good to know that that is the issue, but I don't want to simply drop the index

Comment: Unless that's an indication that the index is doing more harm than good. I added it because `aCol` is a foreign key to another table and is filtered on often, and I do recall that it came out of a specific need or slow query like many of our other indices did.

Comment: So after a bit more research, if I understand composite indices correctly, an index on `(aCol, bCol)` should still be able to be used for a query filtering on `aCol` as it is the first from the left, correct? In that case, I should be able to just delete the offending hash index, run the delete, and then create the composite index

Comment: This is a design issue. It's typically OK to store JSON data as dummy data. However, if you want to process it in any way, you are asking for trouble. I would recommend to perform any JSON processing outside the database.

Comment: @TheImpaler I'm not sure I understand what this has to do with processing JSON data. We do store JSON in this table, but we're not processing it inside the DB in any way, and the query I've shown doesn't reference the JSONB column

Answer (score 2):

You can try to analyze the table by running

```
ANALYZE aTable;
```

to ensure that the table stats are up to date

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just tried this and it seems to have had no effect unfortunately

Comment: it is possible also that there is too much data have you tried partitioning the data

Comment: I haven't tried that and you're right that that is probably something we should look into as our databases have grown quite a bit since the start. But if that was a crippling issue, shouldn't that affect the other 2 environments as well? I mentioned in my post that one of the environments that completes has almost 5x the amount of data as the failing one in both number of records and disk volume

Comment: it is also possible that the index is not optimized, you could just try reseting it by REINDEX INDEX idx_aTable_aCol;

Comment: I think it is in fact related to the index because I also just noticed (and commented on my original post) that dropping the index allows the query to complete instantly. I did try adding the index back as well as doing the `REINDEX` that you mentioned, and no matter what the query won't finish as long as the index is there

Comment: You could just remove the index and try partitioning the data. I'm not sure otherwise how to solve.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with partitions, I'll have to look into it. It seems from doing some research online that having too many partitions can cause performance issues, and I'm not sure how we could put a bound on the number of partitions since `aCol` is a foreign key to another table which is ever-growing, but maybe I'm not properly understanding how to use them. Regardless it does seem like it requires a lot of maintenance overhead